# Nginx client certificate authentication using attribute

Tags: authentication, nginx, certificate

I know that it is possible to do an certificate based authentication for the client.

But is it also possible to restrict the authentication further by checking if a specific field exists in the client certificate?

Found nothing helpful yet

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found a solution.
It should look something like that (not fully tested since I am not that familiar with this nginx scripting).

```
location / {
  if ($ssl_client_s_dn ~ „MyCertProperty“) {
    proxy_pass http://.....
    break;
  }

  return 401 “Not authenticated”
}
```